# Error 13: Type mismatch

Tags: vba, add-in, adobe-indesign

I have a example Add ins of excel:
I call object InDesign as:

```
 Private Sub btnStart_Click()
    Dim pCnt As Integer
    Dim myInDesign As InDesign.Application
    Dim myDoc As InDesign.Document
    Dim myPage As InDesign.Page

    ActiveWorkbook.Colors(17) = RGB(255, 204, 255)
    Set myInDesign = CreateObject("InDesign.Application")
    Set myDoc = myInDesign.ActiveDocument

    Set myInDesign = Nothing
    Set myDoc = Nothing

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Show `Error 13: Type mismatch` at   `Set myInDesign = CreateObject("InDesign.Application")`

Why? how fix? Thanks all.

Comment: Dim myInDesign as Object, or Set myInDesign = New InDesign.Application depending on your addon constructor

Comment: Or a shot in the dark `CreateObject("InDesign.Application.CS5")` if `CS5` is installed?

Comment: I run on win xp ok, but run on win 7 was show error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find answer at http://forums.adobe.com/thread/834780

Delete file C:\ProgramData\Adobe\InDesign\Version 6.0\en_US\Scripting Support\6.0\Resources for Visual Basic.tlb
And run excel and indesign with permission admin